# AppleScript - what are bounds?

Tags: macos, applescript, coordinates, adobe-illustrator, bounds

I am AppleScripting Adobe Illustrator CS3. Here is (part of) my code:

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    tell newDocument
        make new rectangle with properties {bounds:{200.0, 400.0, 300.0, 200.0}}
    end tell
end tell
```

I copied the `make new rectangle` part from page 153 of [this](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/pdfs/IllustratorCS3_AppleScript_Reference.pdf), from Adobe's website.

But what are the `bounds`??? When I run the script, they don't match up with the co-ordinates of the rectangle:

[image: rectangle co-ordinated]

How do I convert from co-ordinates to bounds? My canvas size is `1920` by `1080`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it says in the [reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/pdfs/IllustratorCS3_AppleScript_Reference.pdf) on p.153, the `bounds` are as follows:

1. left-most horizontal
2. top vertical
3. right-most horizontal
4. bottom vertical

bound of the rectangle, measured from the bottom left corner (0, 0). The X and Y coordinates you see will be the coordinates of the rectangle's center point. However, the width and height in your screenshot are strange: when running your code (with `bounds:{200, 400, 300, 200}`), I obtained a rectangle having its center at X=250, Y=300, and dimensions of W=100, H=200, as expected.